# What is the difference between the FAA FNS NOTAM and the FAA PilotWeb NOTAM websites?

Tags: faa, website, notam

I figured out there are currently 2 different FAA websites for NOTAM online search:

- FAA FNS NOTAM website available at https://notams.aim.faa.gov/
- FAA PilotWeb NOTAM website available at https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/

What is the difference of each one? Which one is better to use? Do both of them provide information about Distant (D) NOTAMs, Local (L) NOTAMs and FDC NOTAMs?

Comment: The FAA will transition to FNS October 01, 2016.

Answer (score 4):

I got this response via email from the FAA:

> PilotWeb is considered a Legacy Application based on the USNS, United States NOTAM System. The FNS, Federal NOTAM System, NOTAM Search is a new application. Many Legacy applications will eventually be replaced with the newer FNS applications over the next year. Both applications should be able to provide you with the information you are looking for.

Comment: Can you give a link to that quote?

Comment: It was a FAA response that I got via email.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering because the last page updates at the FNS link are from 2014 (the NOTAMs themselves are current, though) so it was hard to say if the site is actually in use or not. I suspect the key word from the email is "eventually" :-)